# SSRS 2012. Replicate grouping results in report in Query Designer

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

New to SSRS 2012 & struggling.

I have a report - containing a subreport - on client data. When testing with one client (just to make sure everything was OK) it works perfectly.
When the filter's removed, it's timing out (it's actually saying it's been cancelled by the user, which it hasn't).

Obviously the inclusion of the subreport is the problem (as the main report runs fine without it).

My subreport can validly return multiple records per client.  The subreport is grouped on ClientId.  I then have a calculated field - say HasIP - that concatenates two fields (IC and PC ) to produce either YesYes or YesNo.  The tablix is sorted by HasIP by Z to A.

The info in the ClientID footer are what I'm displaying.

```
ClientID    HasIP
22          YesNo - has two records, but since it has a YesYes, I don't want this one
22          YesYes - has two records, but I want the this one
52          YesYes - may only have 1 record, I want this record
76          YesNo - may only have 1 record, I want this record
```

Theoretically a client can't have more than one instance of HasIP=YesYes & shouldn't have more than 2 records.  How can I recreate this effect in Query Designer?  Essentially if HasIP=yesyes, use that record, otherwise use the other record

If I can do this, I can then drop the subreport completely, add this dataset to my main report & use Lookup to get the data.

However, the way our report scenario is set up, I'm not permitted to change the query [I  have to click Query Designer button in Dataset Properties] & I have no experience in MDX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED!!!:**

OK - here's what I've come up with.

**Assign numeric order to IC and PC values**

I concatenated the IC & PC field values together and assigned values and added the ID of the records in the original subreport.  I called this field HasIP

```
=Switch(Fields!IC.Value+Fields!PC.Value="YesYes", 1, 
Fields!IC.Value+Fields!PC.Value="YesNo", 2,  
Fields!IC.Value+Fields!PC.Value="NoNo", 3) & "-" & Fields!R_Name.Value
```

This left me with 2-xxxx, 1-yyyy etc.

I then added a filter to my second dataset:

```
=Left(Fields!HasIP.Value, 1)
```

to exclude values of "NoNo"

**Concatenate HasIP and other fields in Dataset2 (to be used by LookupSet)**

In addition also had to convert the text values into code for output (eg Yes = 1, No = 2, Unknown = 3 etc).  I did this by creating a calculated field in Dataset2 (in the report, not the query) which included the HasIP.  I delimited HasIP from the value by using a dollar sign.

```
=Fields!HasIP.Value & "$" & 
SWITCH(
    left(Fields!CoR.Value, 1)="C", 1, 
    Left(Fields!CoR.Value, 1)="N", 2, 
    True, ""
)
```

This left me with 2-xxxx$2, 1-yyyy$1 etc.

**Sort the LookupSet results**

LookupSet creates an array (and yes, now you know too).  I needed to sort this so that the one I'm after is the first value returned.  This is achieved by copying and pasting the following into the custom code section of your report.  (I've added the code to allow you to sort in reverse if you need it).

```
Function JoinSorted(m_Array As Object()) As String()    
System.Array.Sort(m_Array)
' Array.Reverse(m_Array) 'uncomment this line if you want to sort in reverse

    Dim k As Integer = 0
    For i As Integer = 0 To m_Array.Length - 1
        If i > 0 AndAlso m_Array(i).Equals(m_Array(i - 1)) Then
            Continue For
        End If
        m_Array(k) = m_Array(i)
        k += 1
    Next
    Dim fred As [String]() = New [String](k - 1) {}
    System.Array.Copy(m_Array, 0, fred, 0, k)
    Return fred
End Function
```

You call this by using the following in your report expression:

```
Join(
    Code.JoinSorted(
        LookupSet(Fields!Main_ID.Value,Fields!Main_ID.Value,Fields!YourField.Value,"Dataset2")
    ),""
)
```

So, regardless of how LookupSet wanted to return the array, I always got 1-yyyy$1 first.

**Handling LookupSet output on the report - include default for no records**

For some LookupSet results in the report, I needed return a default value if there were no records returned.  Otherwise I needed to return the assigned value (1, 2, 3 etc).  If found two ways to do this.

This checks to see if the array count [yes, by using length] is greater than zero.  If so, then using a mid function on the array result to return the 14th character:

```
=SWITCH(
    LookupSet(
        Fields!Main_ID.Value, Fields!Main_ID.Value, Fields!Record_Name.Value, "Dataset2"
    )
    .Length=0, 
   2, 
  LookupSet(
      Fields!Main_ID.Value, Fields!Main_ID.Value, Fields!Record_Name.Value, "Dataset2")
  .Length>0,
```

1)

OR
This is the same:

```
=iif(
    LookupSet(
        Fields!Main_ID.Value,Fields!Main_ID.Value,Fields!Main_ID.Value,"Dataset2"
   ).Length>0, 
    Mid(
        Split(
            Join(
                Code.JoinSorted(
                    LookupSet(
                        Fields!Main_ID.Value,Fields!Main_ID.Value,Fields!Main_ID.Value,"Dataset2")
                    )
           ,";")
       ,";").GetValue(0)
    ,  'start point of mid
        InStr(
            Join(
                Code.JoinSorted(
                    LookupSet(
                       Fields!Main_ID.Value,Fields!Main_ID.Value,Fields!Main_ID.Value,"Dataset2"
                    )
                 )
            ,";")
        ,"$")
     +1, 
  1), 
"2"
)
```

**Handling LookupSet output on the report - using of MID when length of value varies**

In some cases the value I needed to return varied in length, eg 2 or 10.  I also needed to return nothing if the LookupSet didn't return any results.  I couldn't use "normal" versions of MID like this:

```
Mid(
   Join(Code.JoinSorted(
        LookupSet(Fields!Main_ID.Value,Fields!Main_ID.Value,Fields!Q12d.Value,"Dataset2")),
        ";"), 
    InStr(
        Join(
            Code.JoinSorted(
             LookupSet(Fields!Main_ID.Value,Fields!Main_ID.Value,Fields!Q12d.Value,"Dataset2")
            ),
        ";"),
   "$")+1, 
    (
        InStr(
            Join(
                Code.JoinSorted(
                    LookupSet(Fields!Main_ID.Value,Fields!Main_ID.Value,Fields!Q12d.Value,"Dataset2")
                    ),
            ";"),
        ";") 
    -
        InStr(
            Join(
                Code.JoinSorted(
                    LookupSet(Fields!Main_ID.Value,Fields!Main_ID.Value,Fields!Q12d.Value,"Dataset2")
                ),
            ";"),
        "$")
    - 1)
  )
```

as it threw #ERROR due to the use of -1 (at the end) making the string a negative length for some records.

So, here is what I could use:

```
=
Mid(
    Split(
       Join(
            Code.JoinSorted(
                LookupSet(Fields!Main_ID.Value,Fields!Main_ID.Value,Fields!Q12b.Value,"Dataset2")
            ),
       ";"),
    ";").GetValue(0)
,
    InStr(
        Join(
            Code.JoinSorted(
                LookupSet(
                    Fields!Main_ID.Value,Fields!Main_ID.Value,Fields!Q12b.Value,"Dataset2")
            ),
        ";"),
    "$")
+1, 
1)
```

By doing this, I could get the results I was after in the details & the footer.

I hope this can help someone else.