# SSRS 2012 using switch statement with LookupSet count in group footer

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Apologies for the long post.

I have an SSRS 2012 report looking at 2 datasets, *Dataset1* and *Dataset2*.
Dataset2 may return 0, 1 or 2 records, so I'm using LookupSet to do this.  From the records returned, I need to display several fields.

The report is grouped by Main_ID.  In the footer of Main_ID, I am counting the number of returned records from Dataset2.

```
=LookupSet(Fields!MainID.Value, Fields!MainID.Value, Fields!Record_Name.Value, "Dataset2").Length
```

This works fine, I'm getting 0, 1 or 2 as appropriate.

In Dataset2 the field:

```
HasIP
```

will be used to determine which record in the array I display (as I need to test a field value in Dataset2).

I'm trying to use a switch statement to use the length of the LookupSet array to return the correct fields.

- If there are no records (eg length of array = 0) then return the
  number 2
- If there is 1 record (eg length of array = 1), then return
  Record_Name
- If there are 2 records (eg length of array = 2), then
  check the field HasIP.
- If HasIP = YesYes, then return the Record_Name of that matching entry
- If HasIP = YesNo, then return the Record_Name of that matching entry.
- If all else fails, return the number 2

This is what I'm up to at the moment.

```
=Switch(
'if no returns returned, display the numeral 2
LookupSet(Fields!Main_ID.Value, Fields!Main_ID.Value, Fields!Record_Name.Value, "Dataset2").Length=0, 2, 


'if one return returned, then display Record Name
LookupSet(Fields!Main_ID.Value, Fields!Main_ID.Value, Fields!Record_Name.Value, "Dataset2").Length=1, 
LookUp(Fields!Main_ID.Value,Fields!Main_ID.Value,Fields!Record_Name.Value,"Dataset2"),


'if two records returned, check the HasIP field.  If HasIP = YesYes, then use this combination first.  
LookupSet(Fields!Main_ID.Value, Fields!Main_ID.Value, Fields!Record_Name.Value, "Dataset2").Length=2 AND
    LookUpSet(Fields!Main_ID.Value,Fields!Main_ID.Value,Fields!HasIP.Value,"Dataset2")(0)="YesYes", 
LookUpSet(Fields!Main_ID.Value,Fields!Main_ID.Value,Fields!Record_Name.Value,"Dataset2")(0), 

LookupSet(Fields!Main_ID.Value, Fields!Main_ID.Value, Fields!Record_Name.Value, "Dataset2").Length=2 AND 
    LookUpSet(Fields!Main_ID.Value,Fields!Main_ID.Value,Fields!HasIP.Value,"Dataset2")(1)="YesYes", 
 LookUpSet(Fields!Main_ID.Value,Fields!Main_ID.Value,Fields!Record_Name.Value,"Dataset2")(1), 


'if two records returned, check the HasIP field.  If HasIP = YesNo, then use this combination second.  
LookupSet(Fields!Main_ID.Value, Fields!Main_ID.Value, Fields!Record_Name.Value, "Dataset2").Length=2 AND 
    LookUpSet(Fields!Main_ID.Value,Fields!Main_ID.Value,Fields!HasIP.Value,"Dataset2")(0)="YesNo", 
LookUpSet(Fields!Main_ID.Value,Fields!Main_ID.Value,Fields!Record_Name.Value,"Dataset2")(0), 

LookupSet(Fields!Main_ID.Value, Fields!Main_ID.Value, Fields!Record_Name.Value, "Dataset2").Length=2 AND 
     LookUpSet(Fields!Main_ID.Value,Fields!Main_ID.Value,Fields!HasIP.Value,"Dataset2")(1)="YesNo", 
LookUpSet(Fields!Main_ID.Value,Fields!Main_ID.Value,Fields!Record_Name.Value,"Dataset2")(1),


'If all else fails, display the number 2
True, 2)
```

I'm getting the correct one returned for 2 records, but getting #ERROR for zero and 1 records.  If I break the formula down to their individual parts:

```
=SWITCH(
LookupSet(Fields!MainID.Value, Fields!MainID.Value, Fields!Record_Name.Value, "Dataset2").Length=0, 
2)
```

This works.  The number 2 is displayed in my report where the are no entries in Dataset2 (the field is blank for any other combination).

If I use:

```
=SWITCH(LookupSet(Fields!MainID.Value, Fields!MainID.Value, Fields!Record_Name.Value, "Dataset2").Length=1, LookUp(Fields!MainID.Value,Fields!MainID.Value,Fields!Record_Name.Value,"Dataset2"))
```

This works fine for when I have 1 record returned from Dataset2 (the field is blank for any other combination).

No matter what I tried with the third part (handling the 2 records), I'm getting issues.  I can get the correct Record Name returned, but I'm getting #ERROR for 0 or 1 records.
I've tried nesting the third part in IIF statements, flipping it round to look at the length first, etc, but no success.

I cannot edit the underlying query of either dataset.

Any guidance much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

See:

[SSRS 2012. Replicate grouping results in report in Query Designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36491211/ssrs-2012-replicate-grouping-results-in-report-in-query-designer)

Essentially it was adding a numeric value to HasIP and also add in the Primary key of the second dataset.
Then sort the LookupSet array to get the value you want.

In the expression, you can use this to assign a default value, even when there are not results returned by the LookupSet:

```
=iif(
    LookupSet(
        Fields!Main_ID.Value,Fields!Main_ID.Value,Fields!Main_ID.Value,"Dataset2"
   ).Length>0, 
    Mid(
        Split(
            Join(
                Code.JoinSorted(
                    LookupSet(
                        Fields!Main_ID.Value,Fields!Main_ID.Value,Fields!Q12b.Value,"Dataset2")
                    )
           ,";")
      ,";").GetValue(0)
    ,  'start point of mid
        InStr(
           Join(
                Code.JoinSorted(
                    LookupSet(
                       Fields!Main_ID.Value,Fields!Main_ID.Value,Fields!Q12b.Value,"Dataset2"
                   )
                )
           ,";")
       ,"$")
     +1, 
 1), 
"2"
)
```